# Calculation returns zero instead of expected result

Tags: c++, debugging, math

I am trying to do a simple calculation : ( (45/100) -  (20+50)/200 )*(10+5)

I am expecting the answer to be 1.5 but  when the programme is compiled , it shows 0.

Can someone figure this out for me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   float   CivIndex = ( (45/100) -  (20+50)/200 )
                  *(10+5);

   cout<<CivIndex; // expect 1.5 but getting 0
}
```

Comment: You are doing [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).  You need to specify float constants, e.g. `45.0f / 100.0f`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer division!

`(45 / 100)` equals 0 when evaluated as an integer, not 0.45 as you'd been hoping.

Make either numerator or denominator a float to get the expected result:

`(45.0 / 100)`

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is integer division, and integer division rounds the result to the closest integer. To correct your code, change it to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   float   CivIndex = ( (45.0/100.0) -  (20.0+50.0)/200.0 )
                  *(10.0+5.0);

   cout<<CivIndex; // expect 1.5 but getting 0
}
```

**Note:** not all `.0` are needed, but just put them to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing integer division.

Specify it as float constants

```
 float   CivIndex = ( (45./100) -  (20+50)/200. )*(10+5);
                        ^ Notice decimal points^
```

Answer (score 2):

All your constants are ints, therefore, the compiler is doing integer math. 45/100 as an int is 0. So is 70/200. 0 - 0*15 = 0. You need to tell the compiler that your constants are floats: 20f, or 20.0 would both work. (For each operation, if at least one constant is a float, the operation will be treated as floating point math.)

Answer (score 2):

In C and several other languages diving two integers result in an integer (integral division). That is `45 / 100` in your code will result in `0` instead of the expected `0.45`

The fix is simple: convert one of the operands to floating point.

```
float   CivIndex = ( (45/100.0) -  (20+50)/200.0 )
              *(10+5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are hoping the integer division as 0.45 but that is actually 0

Try to change this as:

```
 float   CivIndex = ( (45.0/100) -  (20.0+50.0)/200 )
              *(10+5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially evaluating an expression containing only integers. So the 
result will be an integer. 
You can use [casts](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) on the final result of the integer expression.
e.g..

```
int a=20;float b; b=(float)a;cout<<"b: "<<b;
```

Please confirm the syntax.

Or as stated above, you can also make one of you operands as a float/double(if your requirement permits).